# Effect on pressure and/or volume of a real vs. ideal compressor

Tags: jet-engine

I'm looking at the Brayton cycle and trying to understand what happens when we move from the ideal cycle (isentropic compression/expansion) to the real world where we have adiabatic compression/expansion with associated compressor and turbine (in)efficiencies. I understand with adiabatic processes when compressor/turbine efficiencies are less than 1, that there is now an increase in entropy and an increase in temperature vs. the ideal cycle. My question is, with a higher temperature at the end of compression (and expansion), is there any associated change in the pressure and/or volume? Said another way, I'm struggling to square off the occurrence of a higher temperature at the end of compression, but is the pressure and/or volume higher as well?

Comment: If you don't get answer here, you might try https://physics.stackexchange.com/